# JSF quizz application navigation

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, navigation

I created a simple JSF app, that presents a question for the user, and a set of possible answers as radio buttons.

When the user chooses the answer and submit, my bean updates the question and returns the same page, so that the new question is displayed. If the last question is reached, a finish page is returned with the results.

This is working fine, but the problem happens when the user clicks the browser back button and re-submits the form...this increments bean.currentQuestion and breaks my logic.

I tried f:ajax to update the question without page flip, but now i dont know how to present the finish page...

//index.xhtml

```
    <h:form>

        <div class="questionNumberDiv" id ="questionNumberDiv"> 
        <h:outputLabel value="Question #{test.currentQuestion + 1}" for="questionLabel"/>
        </div>
        <br/>                        

        <div class="questionDiv" id="questionDiv"> 
        <h:outputLabel id ="questionLabel" value="#{test.questions[test.currentQuestion].question}"/>
        </div>
        <br/>

        <div class="questionDiv" id="possibleAnswersDiv">
            <h:selectOneRadio requiredMessage="Please, select one answer!" id="radio" layout="pageDirection" value="#{test.currentAnswer}" required="true">
            <f:selectItems value="#{test.questions[test.currentQuestion].possibleAnswers}" var="y"
                           itemLabel="#{y}" itemValue="#{y}" />

            </h:selectOneRadio>
        </div>
        <br/>

        <h:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="requiredMessage">
            <h:commandButton value="next question" action ="#{test.processAnswer}" />                                       
            <h:message for="radio"/>
        </h:panelGrid>

    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Bean method called when user hits 'next Question':

```
public String processAnswer()
{           
    Question q = questions.get(currentQuestion);

    currentQuestion++;
    userAnswers.add(currentAnswer);

    if (currentQuestion == questions.size())
    {
        this.processResults();
        return "finish";
    }
    else 
    {
        return "index";            
    }
}
```

How can i solve this ?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the code you're using? What did you try to do with f:ajax? How is your logic breaking?

Comment: Could you post some code, please?

Comment: Just to make it clearer: The app works fine, the problem is what happens if the user hits the browser back button and re-answer(re-submit) again the same question...To solve this i tried f:ajax to load the new question, and it works, but then i dont know how to return the 'finish'page...Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Despite I don't know much about your logic, I'll try something like this option (taking into account the posibility of receiving a call with all answers processed):

```
public String processAnswer()
{           
    String outcome = null;
    if (currentQuestion <= questions.size()) {
        Question q = questions.get(currentQuestion);

        currentQuestion++;
        userAnswers.add(currentAnswer);
        if (currentQuestion < questions.size()) {
             outcome = "index";
        } else {
             this.processResults();
             outcome = "finish";
        }
    } else {
        outcome = "finish";
    }
    return outcome;
}
```

But it doesn't create a solid code, because the code ignores all submits after using the back button.

I'd really have the currentquestion value in a h:inputHidden, so if you use the back button and you submit you are going to submit the value of currentquestion and the value will match the question answered by the user, so you will be able to update the answer, and go to the next question despite having used the back button n-times.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try that. But the ideal situation is to never allow the user to go back.